# getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments in Selenium driver script

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on Selenium Keyword framework.Below is my code snippet.My script is working fine but I dont understand why this error is coming please help me to resolve this exception.

**Main class**

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Cls_constant.testDataPath,
                Cls_constant.testDataFile, "Sheet1");
        // int rowCount =
        // ExcelUtils.worksheet.getLastRowNum()-ExcelUtils.worksheet.getFirstRowNum();

        for (int irow = 1; irow <= 6; irow++) {

            sActionKeyword = ExcelUtils.getCellData(irow, 3);
            execute_Actions();

        }
    }

    public static void execute_Actions() {
        try {
            ActionKeywords actionKeywords = new ActionKeywords();
            method = actionKeywords.getClass().getMethods();

            // System.out.println(method);
            for (int i = 0; i < method.length; i++) {
                if (method[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(sActionKeyword)) {
                    // method[i].invoke(actionKeywords,param );
                    method[i].invoke(actionKeywords);
                    // System.out.println("Im in for loop");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

**Action Keyword class**

```
 public class ActionKeywords {
    public static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void open_browser() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    public static void navigate() {
        driver.get("https://qa-survey.greatplacet.com/");
    }

    public static void set_uname() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail")).sendKeys("primary@gmail.com");

    }

    public static void set_passwd() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword")).sendKeys("Ch#s3crum8");
    }

    public static void click_login() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginform']/button")).click();
    }
```

**Exception's StackTrace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at ExcecutionEngine.DriverScript.execute_Actions(DriverScript.java:81)
    at ExcecutionEngine.DriverScript.main(DriverScript.java:65)
```

Comment: Is the number of arguments wrong?

Comment: You should read the guide [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)